# How to handle server-side errors using react-query and formik?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik, react-query

This is my login page that uses formik:

```
const login = () => {
  const login = useLoginMutation();

  return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
        onSubmit={(values) => {
            login.mutate(values);
            console.log("isError", login.isError); \\ it is false here
        }}
      >
        <Form>
          <FormInput name="email" label="email" />
          <FormInput name="password" label="password" />
          <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </Form>
      </Formik>
      <div>{login.isError && JSON.stringify(login?.error?.response.data)}</div> \\ but here the login.isError is true
    </div>
  );
};
```

I want to handle server-side errors in formik so I have to access the errors in the onSubmit event. I expected the errors to be available after the mutation, but as you can see, this is not the case.

To make sure there are no errors, I created a ‍‍`div` element that shows the mutation errors. Surprisingly, this time it showed all the errors.

How to access mutation errors in onSubmit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`login.mutate` is an asynchronous function and your `console.log` doesn't actually wait for the mutation to resolve before evaluating `isError`. `react-query` provides a mutate-like method `mutateAsync` that returns a promise resolving the result of the mutation (or throwing an error if there is one). You can then use async/await and try/catch to access errors in `onSubmit`.

```
   <Formik
     initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
     onSubmit={async (values) => {
       try {
         const data = await mutation.mutateAsync(values)
         console.log(data) // data 
       } catch (error) {
         console.error(error) // error
       }
     }}
   >
```

Answer (score 1):

the value of `login.isError` will only change in the next render cycle. If you want to get access to it right in your callback, there are two ways:

1. with `mutate`, you have to use the provided `onError` or `onSuccess` callbacks, which get the data / error passed in as parameter:

```
onSubmit={(values) => {
  login.mutate(values, {
    onError: error => console.log(error),
    onSuccess: data => console.log(data),
  })
```

2. you can use `mutateAsync` instead, which will return `data` or throw an Error, but be aware that you have to do error handling yourselves, otherwise, you will end up with an unhandled promise rejection:

```
onSubmit={async (values) => {
  try {
    const data = await mutation.mutateAsync(values)
    console.log(data)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
}
```

---

unless you need the returned Promise to perform e.g. multiple mutations at the same time and await them all, I would always go for `.mutate` and the callbacks, but that's personal preference. I just think it's easier to grasp and fewer lines of code.